# Passing list of objects to a singular method

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, parameter-passing

As you might know `List<String>` isn't match `List<Object>`.

How can I pass objects like:

```
List<String>
List<Int>
List<className>
```

to a single method?

For example imagine we have a method like:

```
public void _AddListOfObject(string TitleOfDaataGridView, List<Object> Values)
{
    _Temp.Columns[0].Name = TitleOfDaataGridView;               
    foreach (object  i in Values)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I'm not able to pass `List<string>` object to this method.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you are only enumerating (not adding or removing items), you can change the parameter type of `IEnumerable<Object>`. Due to [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), this will allow to pass also e.g. a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for *generic*? Let's use `List<T>` where `T` is a *generic type*:

```
// Method has T generic type
public void _AddListOfObject<T>(string TitleOfDaataGridView, List<T> Values)
{
    _Temp.Columns[0].Name = TitleOfDaataGridView;  
             
    // Note, that i is of generic type T now
    foreach (T i in Values)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

from now on `_AddListOfObject` accepts list of any type:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

_AddListOfObject("TitleInt", list1);
_AddListOfObject("TitleString", list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list of strings to a list of objects and pass that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void _AddListOfObject(List<Object> Values)
    {
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string> {
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        };
        List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
        objects.AddRange(strings);
        _AddListOfObject(objects);
    }
}
```